# How to read multibyte characters from a CSV file using PHP

Tags: php, drupal

I have a CSV file which contains a mixture of English and Chinese characters (it is a list of contacts exported from the Mozilla Thunderbird email program).  I am trying to create a function which can extract the information from this file. It appears that function fgetcsv() does not support multibyte characters.  Since I am running PHP5.2, I do not have access to str_getcsv().

Although the situation above refers to English and Chinese, I am looking for a solution which will work with any language.

Right now I have the function namecards_import_str_getcsv() as my CSV parsing function, which tries to mimic str_getcsv().

```php
function namecards_import_str_getcsv($input, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"', $escape = '\\', $eol = '\n') {
  if (!function_exists('str_getcsv')) {
    if (is_string($input) && !empty($input)) {
      $output = array();
      $tmp    = preg_split("/".$eol."/",$input);
      if (is_array($tmp) && !empty($tmp)) {
        while (list($line_num, $line) = each($tmp)) {
          if (preg_match("/" . $escape . $enclosure . "/", $line)) {
            while ($strlen = strlen($line)) {
              $pos_delimiter = strpos($line, $delimiter);
              $pos_enclosure_start = strpos($line, $enclosure);
              if (is_int($pos_delimiter) && is_int($pos_enclosure_start) && ($pos_enclosure_start < $pos_delimiter)) {
                $enclosed_str = substr($line, 1);
                $pos_enclosure_end = strpos($enclosed_str, $enclosure);
                $enclosed_str = substr($enclosed_str, 0, $pos_enclosure_end);
                $output[$line_num][] = $enclosed_str;
                $offset = $pos_enclosure_end + 3;
              } 
              else {
                if (empty($pos_delimiter) && empty($pos_enclosure_start)) {
                  $output[$line_num][] = substr($line, 0);
                  $offset = strlen($line);
                } 
                else {
                  $output[$line_num][] = substr($line,0,$pos_delimiter);
                  $offset = (!empty($pos_enclosure_start) && ($pos_enclosure_start < $pos_delimiter))? $pos_enclosure_start : $pos_delimiter + 1;
                }
              }
              $line = substr($line,$offset);
            }
          } 
          else {
            $line = preg_split("/" . $delimiter . "/", $line);

            /*
             * Validating against pesky extra line breaks creating false rows.
            */
            if (is_array($line) && !empty($line[0])) {
              $output[$line_num] = $line;
            }
          }
        }
        return $output;
      } 
      else {
        return false;
      }
    } 
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  else {
    return str_getcsv($input);
  }
}
```

This function is called by the following line of code:

```php
  $file = $_SESSION['namecards_csv_file'];

  if (file_exists($file->uri)) {
    // Load raw csv content into a handler variable.
    $handle = fopen($file->uri, "r");
    $cardinfo = array();
    while (($data = fgets($handle)) !== FALSE) {
      $data = namecards_import_str_getcsv($data);
      dsm($data);
      $cardinfo[] = $data[0];
    }
    fclose($handle);
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('CSV file doesn\'t exist'), 'error');
  }
```

In the array of results the strings of Chinese characters are in the correct place in the array by they appear as symbols e.g. "С��".

Another method I had tried before this was to simply use fgetcsv() (See below example).  But in this case the elements of the returned array were empty.

```php
$file = $_SESSION['namecards_csv_file'];

if (file_exists($file->uri)) {
  // Load raw csv content into a handler variable.
  $handle = fopen($file->uri, "r");
  $cardinfo = array();
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    dsm($data);
    $cardinfo[] = $data;
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
else {
  drupal_set_message(t('CSV file doesn\'t exist'), 'error');
}
```

In case you are interested here is the contents of the CSV file:

```
First Name,Last Name,Display Name,Nickname,Primary Email,Secondary Email,Screen Name,Work Phone,Home Phone,Fax Number,Pager Number,Mobile Number,Home Address,Home Address 2,Home City,Home State,Home ZipCode,Home Country,Work Address,Work Address 2,Work City,Work State,Work ZipCode,Work Country,Job Title,Department,Organization,Web Page 1,Web Page 2,Birth Year,Birth Month,Birth Day,Custom 1,Custom 2,Custom 3,Custom 4,Notes,
Ben,Gunn,Ben Gunn,Benny,ben1@asdf.com,ben2@asdf.com,,+94 (10) 11111111,+94 (10) 22222222,+94 (10) 33333333,,+94 44444444444,12 Benny Lane,,Beijing,Beijing,100028,China,13 asdfsdfs,,sdfsf,sdfsdf,134323,China,Manager,Sales,Benny Inc,,,,,,,,,,,
乔,康,乔 康,小康,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,北京市朝阳区,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: As far as I can see, fgetcsv() should support multibyte characters. What makes you think it doesn't? Are you sure the problem isn't elsewhere?

Comment: @Pekka `fgetcsv()` checks for separators on a byte basis, so if the separator **byte** can be part of a multibyte **sequence** things start to break.

Comment: @Eugen ahh, you're right. But a multi-byte byte matching a single-byte byte shouldn't happen, at least not in UTF-8, should it? The only thing that would be a no-no in UTF-8 is a multi-byte separator (**Edit:** ahh, I guess it *can* happen in the second byte, you're right. I withdraw my statement.)

Comment: Benjen - please show how the process goes wrong, what problems you get

Comment: I have modified the original question to include the CSV parsing function I am using.  I switched to this after I discovered that fgetcsv() was not working. Currently this function is picking up the strings of Chinese characters in the right places, but when printed to screen they just appear as strange symbols e.g. "��"

Comment: Please define what your actual problem is, what "not working" means. I have used `fgetcsv` just fine with UTF-8 encoded files in the past.

Comment: @Pekka the second byte was exactly what I meant: splitting there will leave you with a first part, that is invalid on the multibyte stream level and both parts being invalid on a business logic level

Comment: @deceze while I'm sure it's possible to use fgetcsv() on UTF-8 data (and the OP's problem may lie elsewhere) there is a certain danger to it that one should be aware of (I only just realized it myself, see Eugen's and my discussion).

Comment: @Pekka I have modified the question to include more details.  I should point out that I know the function is working (at least partially since the English data is extracted without issue).  It is just the Chinese characters which are causing the headache.

Comment: Benjen I'm not toally sure, but this *could* be because of the problem Eugen and I discuss above - in UTF8, the Chinese characters are multi-byte ones, while the English ones are single byte. Can you show 1:1 an example of a Chinese string and how it gets mutilated?

Comment: @Pekka For example, the following string "北京市朝阳区" becomes "�����г�����" when using the method involving namecards_import_str_getcsv().  In the case of using fgetcsv(), the same string comes back as an empty value (e.g. "北京市朝阳区" becomes "").

Comment: @Pekka, Eugen Even multibyte unaware functions will not split a multibyte UTF-8 character when splitting on ASCII characters only. I.e. the commas in a UTF-8 CSV file are regular ASCII commas, and the way UTF-8 is designed they cannot be confused with any multibyte characters. Unless `fgetcsv` arbitrarily cuts off bytes in the string, there should be no compatibility issue with UTF-8.

Comment: See here for demonstration of `fgetcsv` and UTF-8: http://codepad.viper-7.com/pNN1g1

Comment: As is explained on the manual page, `fgetcsv` is locale sensitive. What's your locale set to?

Comment: @deceze what you say is true for the *start* byte of the multibyte character - it can never have a valid ASCII value - but not necessarily for the *following* bytes, is it? If I understand correctly, they could easily coincide with the ASCII comma (`002C`). (Not that I think this is the case here - it would be too much of a coincidence. Just saying I think it's not 100% safe.)

Comment: @Pekka No. ASCII characters are identical to their UTF-8 equivalent. Any characters that are not in ASCII have *at least* the highest bit set in all bytes of the multibyte character. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8#Design. Non ASCII characters cannot be confused in UTF-8.

Comment: @deceze Makes sense, but if this was the case I would have thought that fgetcsv() would return some kind of string in the place of the Chinese characters.  In this case however, the relevant elements of the returned array are empty.

Comment: @Benjen Then please double confirm that the file is UTF-8 (not UTF-16 or so) and what your locale is set to.

Comment: @deceze ahh, fair enough, I see now. A continuation byte can *never* coincide with an ASCII value. I thought it could. I stand corrected, thanks!

Comment: @deceze The file is definitely UTF-8. The result of setlocale(LC_ALL, 0) is "C". Not exactly sure what "C" means.

Comment: Try `setlocale('en_US.UTF-8')`. That's mostly a shot in the dark though. ;)

Comment: @deceze Thank you.  Just tried `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF-8')` and it appears to work.  `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')` also works.  I am not sure if it is better to use LC_ALL or LC_CTYPE in this case.

Comment: I'm honestly not quite sure about the intricacies of the whole locale system, so I can't say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Just writing up as an answer what was figured out in the comments:</sub>

`fgetcsv` is locale sensitive, so make sure to `setlocale` to a UTF-8 locale.